# How to export editor content as image

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using ngx-quill to create a template designer and I want to be able to export the content of the editor as an image. I can successfully export the content as HTML and PDF but couldn't find a way to export it as an image.

Comment: Please how did you export to PDF. Ive been searching the whole internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use html2canvas, since Quill doesn't provide any built-in way to export its content as an image.

The only thing you need to do is to add a reference on your `quill-editor` element:

```html
<quill-editor #screen 
              format="html" 
              [modules]="quillConfig" 
              placeholder="Some text...">
</quill-editor>

<div class="btn btn-primary" 
     (click)="downloadImage()">DL</div>

<div id="download">
  <img #canvas>
  <a #downloadLink></a>
</div>
```

And catch it in your component, then process and render the image:

```js
  @ViewChild('screen') screen: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('downloadLink') downloadLink: ElementRef;

  downloadImage(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('.ql-editor')).then(canvas => {
      this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'marble-diagram.png';
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
    });
  }
```

[**Here is a working example with html2canvas and ngx-quill**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html2canvas-u1swka)

So for this content:

> [image: editor view]

You'll get the following exported image:

> [image: the exported image]

P.S.: Don't forget to add to `yarn add html2canvas` and `yarn add --dev @types/html2canvas`.